# Apache superset opening two URLs with javascript in deck.gl

Tags: javascript, url, apache-superset, deck.gl

I need to open two URLs from Deck.gl. I am able to open with windows.open. But the thing is I need to pass dynamic paramters based on clicked point.

Below is my code and it opens first and second link, not the third. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

d => "https://latsuperset1.asia.abi.dyn.nesc.nokia.net/superset/dashboard/203/?sitename=" + d.object.extraProps.sitename + "&circle_name=" + d.object.extraProps.circle_name
window.open("https://www.google.com/");
e => "https://latsuperset1.asia.abi.dyn.nesc.nokia.net/superset/dashboard/199/,sitename=" + e.object.extraProps.sitename